# useContext returns undefined in _app.js (Next.js)

Tags: next.js, use-context

Using Next.js, I can get the context value in header.js file without a problem but it returns `undefined` in _app.js

Here is my code.

useLang.js

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'

const LangContext = createContext()

export const LangProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState('en')
  const switchLang = (selected) => setLang(selected)

  return (
    <LangContext.Provider value={{ lang, switchLang }}>
      {children} 
    </LangContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useLang = () => useContext(LangContext)
```

_app.js

```js
import { LangProvider, useLang } from '../hooks/useLang'

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props

  const contexts = useLang()
  console.log(contexts) // ------> undefined. why ???

  return (
    <LangProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </LangProvider>
  )
}
```

header.js

```js
import { useLang } from '../hooks/useLang'

export default function Header() {
  const { lang } = useLang() // ------> works fine here!

  return <> {lang} </>
}
```

I've looked at the Next.js documentation, but nowhere does it mention that you cannot use the state or context in _app.js. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can not get the value of context on _app.js because on top _app.js mustn't children of LangProvider. You just only can use context's value on children component of LangProvider container.

Comment: Don't know why I hadn't thought of that. Thank you!